# Give domain user access to samba folders without join the Ubuntu server to the domain

Tags: ubuntu, permissions, samba, domain

In our environment, we have an Ubuntu server which is not a domain member. this server have also SAMBA service, and so far we use to access the files and folders (from the domain) via the local account on the server.
While trying to access the SAMBA folders via SMB protocol on windows machines, request for user/password is prompted, than we use the local user from the Ubuntu server.

Now there is a new proccess required access to some specific folders. the proccess running on domain-windows servers, by domain-user dedicated to the proccess.

I'm wondering how, and what is the best practice to give access to thise folders for this user - **WHITHOUT** joining the Ubuntu server to the domain.

Many thanks
Yosi.